# Как мне установить Elementary OS (Или любой дистрибутив основанный на Ubuntu) без установки GRUB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, ноутбук, elementary-os

Есть определённые проблемы с установкой GRUB на мой ноутбук, поэтому буду использовать другой загрузчик.

Comment: Гляньте описаниемв вашем загрузчике, как его поставить, можете дать его название и какие проблемы с GRUB?

Comment: ЕМНИП все установщики дистрибутивов linux позволяют пропустить шаг установки загрузчика... было бы странно, если это было бы не так...

Comment: @Fat-Zer всякие юзерфрендли™ дистрибутивы могут пытаться быть умнее пользователя и самостоятельно делать то, что считают нужным :) (правда, как обстоят дела в конкретно убунте/элементари, не помню)

Comment: @andreymal, проверил — бубунта (14.04) по умолчанию действительно ставит grub без лишних вопросов... первое что всплыло в гугле про то как это предотвратить (см. все ответы): https://askubuntu.com/questions/132116/installing-ubuntu-12-04-without-installing-grub

Comment: @Hellseher собираюсь ставить rEFInd. При установка GRUB, что при установке системы, что вручную всё просто намертво зависает, ноутбук перестаёт реагировать на любые команды. Как написал один человек в отзывах к ноутбуку "UEFI этого ноута оказалось жёстко заточенной под виндоус", не знаю насколько это правда, но факт есть факт - GRUB установить не удаётся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решается так:

1. Устанавливаем ОС без загрузчика
2. Устанавливаем в ручную загрузчик rEFInd (Гайд есть на сайте загрузчика)
3. Папку "refind" переименовывать в "BOOT", а файл "refind_x64.efi" в "bootx64.efi"

Может возникнуть проблема с выключением ноутбука, решаем так:
В refind.conf прописываем параметр ядра "pci=nocrs" в строке "options".